# How can I say to my app scroll up or down without do the scroll with my finger?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have created an application where I have a listview, so now I'm working to implement the sdk of samsung to manage the air gestures and its working ok, because the app recognize when I swipe without touch the screen, but what I would like do is implement a scroll `down` and `up` when the user do the gesture. so my question is How can I say to my app scroll up or down?? should be something to emulate the same thing as the user do when he press the screen and scroll

Comment: Why don't you look for an answer on the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside ListView you can use smoothScrollToPositionFromTop or smoothScrollBy methods